# Maven: How are artifacts built if they have their own dependencies?

Tags: java, maven, jar

Let's say that I created a new artifact, let's call it "MyArtifact". In order to create this artifact I had to use 3 dependencies, let's call them "Dependency1", "Dependencies2" and "Dependency3".

If I just create a jar file for this artifact using Maven, the resultant jar file will not include the class files for the dependencies, which will make the jar file useless.

I understand that the right design is that the artifact should include a "reference" to its dependencies and once the application installs the artifact, it will automatically install the artifact's dependencies.

If so, what Maven plugin should I use in order to create an artifact that when it's installed on some application, it will reference the application to the artifact dependencies?

Comment: In terms of Maven design, your artifact would just contain references to those other dependencies.  When Maven is building with your artifact, it would know how to download the other dependencies.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I agree. But, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you build a jar as library, i.e. to be used as dependency by other artifacts, then you just add your dependencies as `<dependency>` entries.

If someone uses your library in their Maven project (and has also configured the same repositories as you), then these dependencies are found automatically.

If you build a jar to be run somewhere as an application, then you usually include the dependencies, either by building a runnable jar with the Maven assembly or Maven shade plugin, or by zipping up a directory of libraries and adding a start shell script.